# Js / Php - Am I sending this value correctly?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to collect the index of my combo box.
I would like to be able to change the index, and then have a bunch of fields changed based on the new index. Am I doing this right so far?

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getCombo(sel) {
     var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex]; 
     $.get(document, {type: value}); 
}
</script>

// Misc code here

<td class="bold"><label for='addType'>Select Type to Add : </label>
    <select name="addType" id="combo" onchange="getCombo(this)">
        <option value="book">Book</option>
        <option value="author">Author</option>
        <option value ="publisher">Publisher</option>
        <option value="customer">Customer</option>
    </select>
<?php
    $type['type'] = $_GET['value'];
?></td>
```

Comment: Note you can get the value of a select as with any form input, by using the element's "value" property: `sel.value`.

Comment: `$.get(document` You can't do that.  Otherwise, this looks fine.  The only thing I would suggest is to *not* use inline event attributes, and use event handlers instead.

Comment: Are you having an issue with the code?  What happened when you tested it?  Did it work?  Not work?

Comment: Have not tested it yet, never used javascript so I wanted to see if I was even remotely close. I will change up the $.get(document, thanks.

Comment: I suggest testing code before asking here.  You'll learn better by trying it out yourself.  This site is for specific issues with code.  Test it out, then come back if you have a problem. :-)

Comment: The best way to learn is to try and fail yourself first, then if you really get stuck seek help.

Comment: `document` isn't a string (and when converted to one, isn't very useful).  `$.get` expects a string as the first parameter; the URL to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem try this following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#combo").change(function(){
           var value = $(this).val();
           $.get(document, {type: value});
      });
 </script>

 <td class="bold"><label for='addType'>Select Type to Add : </label>
    <select name="addType" id="combo" >
       <option value="book">Book</option>
       <option value="author">Author</option>
       <option value ="publisher">Publisher</option>
       <option value="customer">Customer</option>
    </select>
<?php
    $type['type'] = $_GET['type']; // beacuse 
?>
</td>
```